# BizTalk WCF-SQL Receive location started polling in both server in Multi-Server environment

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-2016

I have a BizTalk receive location which is WCF-SQL. I have scheduling in this receive location to run daily at 9 am to 9:30 am. Also i have Typed polling which checks for a table. This works fine in BizTalk single server. But in multi server environment(2 servers) I see that receive location is started polling in both server with around 30 seconds difference. Is this expected behaviour. In case SFTP adapter this is expected and  we use clustered host instance to avoid it.

So is this expected in WCF-SQL port as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour for the WCF-SQL adapter, and as you noted, SFTP, also FTP(s), MSMQ and POP3.  All of these adapters need to run on a host instance that is clustered in a multi-node environment to avoid duplicates.

See Considerations for [Running Adapter Handlers within a Clustered Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/considerations-for-running-adapter-handlers-within-a-clustered-host1) , which unfortunately does not specify WCF-SQL, and the older article [Clustering Receiving Hosts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/clustering-receiving-hosts) only mentions the older SQL adapter and also the old SAP adapter.

Comment: Can i get any reference of microsoft document which states this. I got one more post from stackoverflow with same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165668/biztalk-receive-port-reading-twice-from-db

Comment: I've added some references, unfortunately none address WCF-SQL specifically, but yes, the options in that answer on that other question still stand.